# Cannot launch Mathematica from terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, shortcuts, binary, mathematica

I have *Ubuntu desktop 16.04.6 LTS xenial*. My Mathematica 12.1 is working and, while I can launch it from the GUI shortcut, I cannot launch it from the terminal.

I don't know if something went wrong during installation, but there are no `mathematica` binaries in `/usr/bin/`, and `/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/12.1/Executables/` is not in the `$PATH`. Should I do one of these manually?

How can I solve this?

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Sorry! It is done.